# Android Jsoup.connect(String).execute() fails

Tags: java, android, asp.net, jsoup

I'm attempting to access selected data from the html table that is returned from http://reednavigation.com/lunars/lunars_v5.asp (full path works in browser and can be found in code below in the commented parameter Almanac_full).

I've tried replicating code seen elsewhere on stackoverflow for similar problems but can't get past the first Jsoup.connect().execute line. It always lands in my exception catch.

I am a relative novice at Android and Java, so any ideas (and as much tolerance as you can muster) will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Code:**

```
    try {
        String Month= "August";
        String Day = "9";
        String Year = "2014";
        String Almanac = "http://reednavigation.com/lunars/lunars_v5.asp";
        //String Almanac_full = "http://reednavigation.com/lunars/lunars_v5.asp?BodySel=Include+Navigation+Stars&todaycheck=0&GMTmonth=August&GMTday=9&GMTyear=2014&gmtsel=Gr.+Mean+Time&hristep=Every+Hour&degformat=dd.dddd&usesha=on&OutType=N&LatDeg=&LatMin=&LatName=N&LonDeg=&LonMin=&LonName=W";

        Response response1 = Jsoup.connect(Almanac).method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .data("BodySel", "Include+Navigation+Stars")
                .data("todaycheck", "0")
                .data("GMTmonth", Month)
                .data("GMTday", Day)
                .data("GMTyear", Year)
                .data("gmtsel", "Gr.+Mean+Time")
                .data("hristep", "Every+Hour")
                .data("degformat", "dd.dddd")
                .data("usesha", "on")
                .data("OutType", "N")
                .data("LatDeg", "")
                .data("LatMin", "")
                .data("LatName", "N")
                .data("LonDeg", "")
                .data("LonMin", "")
                .data("LonName", "W")
                .timeout(10000)
                .execute();

        Map<String, String> cookies = response1.cookies(); //Get the session cookie

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(Almanac).method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .data("BodySel", "Include+Navigation+Stars")
        .data("todaycheck", "0")
        .data("GMTmonth", Month)
        .data("GMTday", Day)
        .data("GMTyear", Year)
        .data("gmtsel", "Gr.+Mean+Time")
        .data("hristep", "Every+Hour")
        .data("degformat", "dd.dddd")
        .data("usesha", "on")
        .data("OutType", "N")
        .data("LatDeg", "")
        .data("LatMin", "")
        .data("LatName", "N")
        .data("LonDeg", "")
        .data("LonMin", "")
        .data("LonName", "W")
        .timeout(10000)
        .cookies(cookies)
        .post();

        String title = doc.title();

        Elements BodyElements = doc.getElementsContainingText(Body);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error occured reading URL.");
        OutputText.setText("Error occured reading URL.");
    }
```

Comment: So, you get an exception.. Perhaps it would be good to include what exception and the stacktrace in your question for easier resolving?

Comment: @DanielB well, perhaps ill do that... Once I work out how.

Comment: The `catch` block will eat your exception, just print out the stack trace from like `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` and post it in your question.

Comment: @DanielB Sorry, haven't been able to work out how to see the stacktrace. e.getMessage() is null in Watch, and LogCat reports:`08-11 22:44:52.648: E/InputEventReceiver(19907): Exception dispatching input event.
08-11 22:44:52.658: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19907): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
08-11 22:44:52.803: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19907): java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was my attempt to perform a networking operation on the application's main thread.

This Q and As is the go to for the solution (Async) [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Thanks to @DanielB for guiding me toward the answer.